# Refresh An Activity , but it should not clear previous selection areas

Tags: android

i am having spinner to change languages. i want to refresh activity but it should not affect the selection i have done in spinner for language.
i have try it using intent but it use the default text to spinner.
This is code of MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText name , sname, pass;
    Button submit;
    Spinner languages;
    Locale mylocal;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
        sname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_surnm);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_pass);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        languages = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_lang);
        languages.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int pos, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (pos==1){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Selected :" +languages.getSelectedItem().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setLocale("en");
                }
                else if(pos ==2){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Selected :" +languages.getSelectedItem().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setLocale("de");
                }
                else if(pos ==3){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Selected :" +languages.getSelectedItem().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setLocale("fr");
                }
                else if(pos ==4){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Selected :" +languages.getSelectedItem().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setLocale("hi");
                }
                else if(pos==5){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Selected :" +languages.getSelectedItem().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setLocale("gu");
                }   
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }
    public void setLocale(String lang){

         mylocal = new Locale(lang);
         Locale.setDefault(mylocal);
         Resources res = getResources();
         Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
         conf.locale = mylocal;

         DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
         res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
         //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         Intent refresh = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
         refresh.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         startActivity(refresh); 

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put more details in your post

Answer (score 0):

I tried this by using ListPopupWindow like below. Check my full code at: http://hastebin.com/ataruxafuw.xml:

```
private void changeLanguage(String str) {
    languageToLoad = str;
    locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    implementPopup();
}

private void implementPopup() {
    btnLanguages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowPopup);
    listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(MainActivity.this);
    listPopupWindow.setAdapter(
            new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, products));
    listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(btnLanguages);
    listPopupWindow.setWidth(300);
    listPopupWindow.setHeight(400);
    listPopupWindow.setModal(true);
    listPopupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

            listPopupWindow.dismiss();
            if (pos == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Selected :" + products[pos], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                changeLanguage("en");
            } else if (pos == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Selected :" + products[pos], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                changeLanguage("de");
            }

            btnLanguages.setText(products[pos]);

        }
    });
}
```